# Application_End equivalent in ASP.NET Core rc2?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have not been able to find any information on whether or not there is an override that will be called when a ASP.NET Core "application" terminates. Basically an equivalent to the old `Application_End` in MVC4.
I found some info on how it is handled in MVC5 but that does not apply for Core rc2.

Anybody has some information on this?